# Which scripture mention that dattatreya belongs to fifth ashram?

Tags: scripture, dattatreya, varnashrama

The [four ashramas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashrama_(stage)) in sanathan dharma are: Brahmacharya (student), Grihastha (householder), Vanaprastha (forest walker/forest dweller), and Sannyasa (renunciate).

I heard that Dattatreya does not belong to four ashrams. And he belongs to fifth ashram.

Which scripture mentions that fact?